# setState hooks in axios post request not working

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-state

```
const Login=(props)=>{

const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const [user, setUser] = useState({});


const login = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post('/login',{email, password})
    .then(response => {
        setUser(response.data)
        console.log(response.data, user, "user data");
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

[this is the empty user data i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJEHM.png)

this is my code for the login request its fetching the data and logging it in the console but it doesnt want to set the user

Comment: you don't see the user being printed in the console am I right in your .then call?

Answer (score 0):

Because `setUser` is async. So the new state only update when component rerender. You can check by move `console.log` outside the `login` function

```
console.log(user, "user data");
return(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use useEffect to check state after component rerender:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(user);
}, [user])
```